# Any fix for Instabug captures blank screen and video for Flutter application (android build)

Tags: android, flutter

I want to integrate some bug reporting or feature request SDK in my app. I got to know about Instabug, i gave it a shot with my flutter application (android build).

The SDK captures blank screen for the app. Is it because of flutter or I have made some mistake in integrating it.

Here is how my Application class looks:

```
package next.home

import com.instabug.library.Instabug
import com.instabug.library.invocation.InstabugInvocationEvent
import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication


class MyApplication() : FlutterApplication() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        Instabug.Builder(this, "TOKEN")
                .setInvocationEvents(InstabugInvocationEvent.SHAKE, InstabugInvocationEvent.SCREENSHOT)
                .build()
    }
}
```

I am fine anyone could suggest some another SDK that work with flutter.

Comment: Are Flutter views hardware-accelerated? Also, Instabug currently has no official support for Flutter, but there's probably a workaround to get it to work.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to sort it out?

Comment: Nope. Wrote an email an to instabug. They said they are working on it and will inform once they push the update.

Comment: Instabug's Android SDK now captures videos using Media Projection, so capturing should work fine on Flutter. Please update to the latest release and give it a try.

Comment: @HarshBhikadia Does it work on flutter now?

Comment: @nAndroid This [instabug plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/instabug) works but is not recommended for production